i am trying to download file from s3 in spring boot lambda but i am always getting an invalid zip file

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Result;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

@RestController
public class DownloadController {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 s3Client;

    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "fftodcf";

    @GetMapping("/conversion/feature-file/{batchId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFiles(@PathVariable String batchId) {
        String keyPrefix = "converted/" + batchId + "/";
        
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {

            // Get the list of files in the specified S3 folder
            ListObjectsV2Result result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(BUCKET_NAME, keyPrefix);

            // Loop through all the files and add them to the zip
            for (S3ObjectSummary summary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                try (S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(BUCKET_NAME, summary.getKey())) {
                    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(summary.getKey().replace(keyPrefix, "")));
                    
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = s3Object.getObjectContent().read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                }
            }

            // Finish the zip file
            zipOutputStream.finish();

            // Create a ByteArrayResource from the output stream
            ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

            // Set headers to download the zip file
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + batchId + "_files.zip");

            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
                    .body(resource);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
}

after download i got this error
Compressed (zipped) Folders Error
Windows cannot open the folder.
The Compressed (zipped) Folder
0baf1795-9d7d-4001-8765-56725c06ca1e_files.zip' is invalid.
i was expecting a zip will be downloaded will all the files in it
i deployed this code on aws lambda but i am not able to download the files always getting a invalid zip file ,and i am pretty sure that the folder contains files

What size is the downloaded file after you receive it?  I don't categorically see any code indicates ServletOutputStream write bytes , albeit it's a web service port (REST), and probably a "get".  Where is it's WSDL XML definition file for the service (code) auto-generated.

Also, get the FTP and check the zip file was properly created with content on the server. If you are using nix server, then use no compression because Windows zip codecs can differ from what Java potentially has used!

The downloaded file is of just 7kb.and while iam trying to open it says invalid zip

It seems the issue is in packaging of zip because if I tried to download a folder that has 100 filed then it's size increases to 93kb ,but still on trying to open it says invalid zip.

NB headers, body both go on a "Response" object NOT a response entity, content length is part of the headers on a response.
